# iOS app rejected because of a Unity IAP issue

Tags: ios, iphone, validation, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I recently submitted one of my Unity games for App Review today and it got rejected. The rejection was related to an In-App Purchase issue in **iOS 15.3** (which, at the time of writing, is the latest version). Their response is below:

> ---
>
> We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 15.3 on Wi-Fi.

> Next Steps
> When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead.
>
> ---

A couple things to note. I'm not even using server-side validation for my IAPs. For this particular game, I'm using local validation. My IAPs also worked in the sandbox environment. Both the test builds and production builds are running identical code. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

I'm using the most recent version of the IAP package (**4.1.2** at the time of writing) with **Unity 2020.1.15f1**.

Comment: For problems like this its arguably better to approach technical support at Unity and/or Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Unity made a patch for the IAP package that fixed the problem. My game got approved!

Comment: Can you please explain in details please.